# Why isn't overload resolution picking the std::vector overload of my template function?

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code, I want it to use the `std::vector` version of `f()` if I call it with a `std::vector` argument, but it's using the first one and complaining that `std::to_string(const std::vector<T>&)` doesn't exist. My understanding of template overload resolution is that it should use the "more specialized" version. Somehow I think that doesn't apply here, because this is a function overload rather than a template overload. But it's not even using the normal function overload resultion rules, or else it would complain about an ambiguous call to `f()`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
std::string f(T&& member) {
    return std::to_string(member);
}

template<typename T>
std::string f(const std::vector<T>& member) {
    return std::to_string(member[0]);
}

int main() {
    int a = 42;
    printf("%s\n", f(a).c_str()); // OK

    std::vector<int> b = { 42 };
    printf("%s\n", f(b).c_str()); // ERROR: to_string doesn't have a std::vector overload

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Overload resolution would prefer to not add cv-qualification if it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type deduced by the forwarding reference is `std::vector<int>&`, as opposed to the `const std::vector<int>&` of the other overload. So when comparing the overloads, your non-const argument is a better match for the non-const qualified reference parameter, and so that one is chosen.

One way to address it is to account for both const qualifications with the help of another overload.

```
template<typename T>
std::string f(std::vector<T>& member) {
    return f(std::as_const(member));
}
```

Here we obtain a const reference to `member` with the help of [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) and delegate to your original overload. You may want to provide an rvalue specific overload too, since the forwarding reference will deduce a better match for those as well when compared to your `vector` overloads.